# SlidingDrawer broke ViewPager workng

Tags: android-layout, android-viewpager, slidingdrawer

I have a simple layout with some page title, ViewPager and SlidingDrawer.

There is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

    <SlidingDrawer
            android:id="@+id/main_layout_slider"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:handle="@+id/main_layout_arrow_image"
            android:content="@+id/main_layout_opinions"
            >
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_layout_arrow_image"
                android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_layout_opinions"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/main_layout_opinions_categories"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/main_layout_opinions_settings"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/main_layout_opinions_search"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </SlidingDrawer>

</LinearLayout>
```

Without SlidingDrawer it work perfectly but, when i add it, ViewPager is lose control.

And one more thing why Sliding Drawer take all view, not only height of buttons, how can I chane it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a relativelayout instead of the linear layout and in your sliding drawer mention this android:layout_below="@+id/idOfYourHeaderWhichShouldNotBeCovered"